# Event to copy table to another table every hour without deleting

Tags: sql-server, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to automatically copy all rows in Table1 to Table2 every hour. In Table2 the rows will just be added to the existing ones without being deleted.

I've been how to do this in Sql Server, and I've found two potential options, but as my experience with SQL is very limited I do now know how to proceed, but in times of need...one must step up.

Option one CREATE EVENT Session

Option two Create Trigger

I don't know which one is best to put in place, and I also do not know exactly how to set it up. Bear in mind I do not have access to SQL Agent Server.

Can someone give me a hand please?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a simple stored procedure

   SET ANSI_NULLS ON
   GO
   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
   GO

   CREATE PROCEDURE sp_CopyData

   AS
   BEGIN

   ```
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO Table2
    SELECT * FROM Table1
   ```

   END
   GO
2. Create a batch file CopyData.bat to run stored procedure via sqlcmd utility

   sqlcmd -S ServerName -d DatabaseName -E -Q "EXEC sp_CopyData"
3. Create windows scheduled task to run batch file as per your required schedule.